# Android RecyclerView not updating TextView

Tags: android, observer-pattern

I want to change asynchronous data in a recycler View.

When method `SetText()` is called, nothing happens until I scroll.

```
class MainAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MainAdapter.MyViewHolder> {
    private Context context;
    private SortedList<City> items;

    public MainAdapter(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public void add(City item){
        items.add(item);
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View row = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false);
        return new MyViewHolder(row);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        holder.tvTitle.setText(String.format("%d %s", items.get(position).getId(), items.get(position).getName()));

        Observable<String> observable = Observable.create(new Observable.OnSubscribe<String>() {
            @Override
            public void call(Subscriber<? super String> subscriber) {
                try {
                    //Do somethin in Background
                    Thread.sleep(3000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                subscriber.onNext(items.get(position).name);
                subscriber.onCompleted();
            }
        }).subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation());

        observable.subscribe(new Subscriber<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onCompleted() {
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable e) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onNext(String text) {
                holder.tvRowText.setText(text);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return items.size();
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
        super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
    }

    static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        @BindView(R.id.row_title)
        public TextView tvTitle;

        @BindView(R.id.row_text)
        public TextView tvRowText;

        MyViewHolder(View row) {
            super(row);
            ButterKnife.bind(this, row);
        }
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Calling `notifyDatachanged(i)` in `onNext()` is not working.

Comment: I like to handle these kinds of this with [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try using below code:

```
holder.tvRowText.setText(text);
```

inside a post call (which will run it on **UI thread**) like this:

```
holder.tvRowText.post(new runnable... emitted for brevity){
holder.tvRowText.setText(text);
}
```